# Forbidden access when using csrf (express + node)

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I am trying to generate CSRF tokens in express.  I have checked related queries and none of them seems to help me.  I have the below code in my app.js

```
var app = express();
var connect = require('connect');
// Disable CSRF for some requests
var conditionalCSRF = function (req, res, next) {
    var whitelist = ['/login'];

    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        next();
        return;
    }
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.url) !== -1) {
        next();
    } else {
        //req.session._csrf || (req.session._csrf = connect.utils.uid(24));
        (express.csrf())(req, res, next);
    }
};

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); 
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.session({ 
        secret: 'applecake',
        key: 'sid',
        cookie : {
            maxAge : 604800,
            path:"/"
        }
    }));
    app.use(conditionalCSRF);
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

My form is a simple form like this

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/conversationlist" method="post">

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value=token />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Get ConversationList"/>
</div>
```

I login using a /login URI and that works fine which is not part of the CSRF protection.  Once I try any other URI,

I do not see the CSRF token being set and also I receive a forbidden message

```
Express
 403 Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (C:\Career\Node.JS\ExpressCHLogging\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (C:\Career\Node.JS\ExpressCHLogging\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\csrf.js:82:55)
at C:\Career\Node.JS\ExpressCHLogging\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\csrf.js:54:7
at Object.ondone (C:\Career\Node.JS\ExpressCHLogging\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\uid2\index.js:46:8)
```

Any idea why I receive forbidden access.

Comment: Can you please post your route handler that shows how you're communicating `token` to your view?

Comment: app.post('/conversationlist', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  conversationlist.start(req,res,req.session.cn);
}); This is what I have for the URL that I am trying.  For authentication I use passport and that gets called during /login.

Comment: Specifically, you set `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value=token />`  Where does `token` come from?  Do you have a `res.render` call somewhere where you pass it in?

Comment: I tried to add res.locals.token = req.session._csrf; in the else part of conditionalCSRF.  But I dont see any impact.  May be I am adding it to the wrong place.  Also If I try this - app.use(function(req, res, next) { res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', eq.csrfToken());  res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();  next();});, it applies csrf protection for all URL which I do not want.  Any suggestion, what exactly I have to add?

Comment: `(express.csrf())(req, res, next);` this line is bad because it will generate a middleware function for each request. And express.csrf need to be run on both GET/POST, you code show that it run on POST only.

Comment: I dont get to see any change even if I remove the POST check.  How should the express.csrf() line be changed?  I have tried many possibilities by reading other posts but none helps.  Any idea?

Comment: @user2731628 `var handler=express.csrf();` in global scope and then use `handler` inside `conditionalCSRF`. Plus use `handler(req, res, next);` instead of `next();` when dealing with non-POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `token` variable is available to your rendering engine.

For example, if you use swig, then you should wrap it with the curly braces, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={{ token }} />
```

You can make sure that the token is properly generated by opening the form in the browser and looking at the page source code. If the csrf value has been assigned properly, it will be shown in place of `token`, otherwise it will be empty.